# how to invoke function that inside it you can access to argument through this?

Tags: javascript

I have following function:

```
function outer(){
   index = 1;
   inner();
}

function inner(){ 
 alert(this.index);
}
```

I want to see 1 in alert. Also I want that function inner would without arguments.

Is it possible?

Comment: `this` is for accessing properties of an object, NOT for accessing local variables.  Javascript does not provide a means of accessing local variables via an object reference unless you put all your variables in an object and pass a reference to that object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can specify the context manually when invoking a function with [Function.prototype.call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)

```
function outer () {
    this.index = 1;
    inner.call(this);    
}
```

Comment: But it doesn't work if inner have one argument. Can you advise at this way?

Comment: what do you want to pass into inner?

Comment: The "call" function is different to just calling it using the normal syntax. Refer to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call  - You can see a working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/r77gg0t4/

Comment: From your jsfiddle, it looks like you're passing in arguments correctly to inner.

Comment: Yes) this link was as answer to my own question)

Answer (score 0):

If you define the `index` variable outside the scope of the `outer()` function, it will be available to both functions.

```
var index = 0;

function outer() {
  index = 1;
  inner();
}

function inner() {
  alert(index);
}

outer(); // alerts "1"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use apply the functions to an object, which would control the context:

```
function blarg() {
    var self = this;

    self.outer = function(){
       self.index = 1;
       self.inner();
    };

    self.inner = function(){
        alert(self.index);
    };

    self.outer();     // Call it in the constructor

    self.go = function() {
        self.outer();     // Or in another function
    };
}

var blargObj = new blarg();
blargObj.go();
```

Comment: Your code only works because you are adding index to the global object.  You'll find that when executing your code in a browser window.index = 1 and the context created from new blarg() does not have an index property.

Comment: Thanks, @Steven. Always got to be careful assuming what "this" actually is.